# Autowiring same class instance in two beans

Tags: spring, autowired

I have the following code inside the beans xml configuration file:

```
<bean class="com.cisco.nms.discovery.test.persister.PersistenceServiceMock" id="persistenceService"/>

<bean class="com.cisco.nms.discovery.test.persister.PersistenceServiceMock" id="emsLocator"/>

<bean class="com.cisco.nms.discovery.test.persister.PersistenceServiceMock" id="navigator"/>
```

as a result I get 3 different instances of classes autowired. 
I want to have the same class instance autowired to all these autowired variables.
How can I do it??

Comment: What do you want to inject in what? All you have there is 3 bean definitions.

Comment: Add scope="singleton" to your xml and delete the bean you do not use.

Comment: I cant delete any bean... Each id u see there is the name of some autowired variable I have in the code.  I  want that all of the autowired variables reffer to same class instance of the persistenceServiceMock.

Comment: autowiring is done byType, why you need ids ?

Comment: Can you show an example?  Is that will help me to fix the problem?